# SAPUI5/Javascript Interval 30 sec, Display MessageBox as a Popup when new changes occur on the DB

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to display an error messageBox for every "102" status.

```
onInit: function () {
        var counter = {};
        var sUrl = "/api/equipmentReport/getMachineOverview.xsjs";

        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        this.modelRefresh = setInterval(this.refreshModel.bind(this), 30000, sUrl, oModel);
        oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function (oEvent) {
            this.buildComboBox(oEvent.getSource().getData());
            if (oEvent.getParameter("success") === true) {
                var oModelData = oEvent.getSource().getData();
                oModelData.equipments.forEach(function(o){
                    // o.iotTimestampDate = o.iotTimestamp !== null ? new Date(o.iotTimestamp) : "";
                    counter[o.registeredProductId] = o.telemetryStatus;
                })
            }
            this.getPopupMessageForOfflineMachines(counter);
            oEvent.getSource().updateBindings(true);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "rootModel");

        }.bind(this));

        oModel.attachEventOnce('requestCompleted', {
            oModel: oModel
        }, this.restoreApplicationState.bind(this));
        oModel.loadData(sUrl, false);



        oModel.setSizeLimit(1000000);
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
        this.oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        this.oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.handleRouteMatched, this);
        var oHashChanger = sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.getInstance();
        var sHash = oHashChanger.getHash();
        if (sHash) {
            var sAppStateKey = /(?:sap-iapp-state=)([^&=]+)/.exec(sHash)[1];
            if (sAppStateKey) {
                sap.ushell.Container
                    .getService("CrossApplicationNavigation")
                    .getAppState(this.getOwnerComponent(), sAppStateKey)
                    .done(this.restoreAppState.bind(this));
            }
        }
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

so firstly I am creating an object(registeredProductId -> status)

```
40000000.H: "102"
40000001.H: "113"
40000002.H: "113"
40000003.H: "113"
40000004.H: "113"
40000005.H: "113"
40000006.H: "113"
40000007.H: "113"
40000008.H: "113"
40000009.H: "113"
40000010.H: "101"
40000011.H: "113"
40000012.H: "113"
40000015.H: "103"
40000023.H: "103"
40000026.H: "103"
40000027.H: "113"
40000028.H: "102"
40000029.H: "103"
```

after that in my function I get status 102, and I need to check somehow the object. If the registeredProductId  is already there and if it has status !== 102, it is warning-relevant, so that the Popup appears only once per Status and only when the service data changes.

```
getPopupMessageForOfflineMachines: function(counter) {
       console.log(counter);
       for (var key in counter) {
            if(counter[key] == "102"){
                MessageBox.warning(key);
            }
        }

    },
```

if so, it is warning-relevant

The problem is that the model/service refreshes every 30 seconds and my Popup comes out every 30 seconds.

I would really appreciate any pointers on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of and compare with the previous values. Concretely, add a variable e.g. `previousCounter`, and then in your `getPopupMessageForOfflineMachines` function, use

```
if(counter[key] == "102" && counter[key] !== previousCounter[key]){
  MessageBox.warning(key);
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?